# How to refer to Word Field by name in VBA Code?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-field

I want to update a word field content using VBA. I already have a code that works, but I have to refer to the field's index instead of field's name, which I would prefer.

The code I have is as follows:

```
Sub UpdateField()
  Dim myString As String
  myString = "asdf"
  ActiveDocument.Fields(1).Result.Text = myString
End Sub
```

Suppose that the field's name is MyField1. The following code will not work (I get the Run-time error '13': Type mismatch'.

```
Sub UpdateField()
  Dim myString As String
  myString = "asdf"
  ActiveDocument.Fields("MyField1").Result.Text = myString
End Sub
```

I create my word fields from File Menu > Informations > Advanced Properties > Custom Tab.

So, how to refer to the field's name when we want to update its content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are `DocProperty` fields. If you press Alt+F9 you'll see the field *codes*.

A `DocProperty` field references (links to) a Document Property. The Document Property has the name, but this does not "name" the field. Nor is it possible to *update* a `DocProperty` field directly since it links to the Document Property. It might be possible to make it *temporarily* display something else, but this will be lost any time the field is updated.

In order to update a `DocProperty` field it's necessary to update the underlying Document Property. For example

```
Sub EditDocPropUpdateDocPropertyField()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim prop As Office.DocumentProperty
    Dim propName As String
    Dim newPropValue As String

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    propName = "MyField"
    newPropValue = "new value"
    Set prop = doc.CustomDocumentProperties(propName)
    prop.value = newPropValue
    doc.Fields.Update

End Sub
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing!! I was happy that I had a partial solution before, from @John Korchok answer, but now I have a fullsize solution, and elegance still present S2.

Comment: Glad it helped! John may well have provided the same, if all the necessary information had been in the question from the beginning. Always try to think of everything that could be relevant before asking and answers will come more quickly and accurately :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the VBE, the **Object Browser** is a great way to find out what's possible. When I find **Word>Field** and click on it, I see a list of the members of Field. *Name* is not in that list. This means that the field object does not have a Name property. That's why you get the error.

You can work around this. One way is to create a bookmark around the field in question. Then in code, find the bookmark by name, then find the field by index inside the bookmark range.

Comment: John Korchok, thank you for the useful reply! I accepted your answer and edited my asking, but after that I realized a new answer from @Cindy Meister that solve the problem without the need of bookmarking, and without the worry of updating the fields and get back them to their real values. Then I changed my accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sample to set text to fields by field name:

```
ThisDocument.FormFields.Item("MyField1").Result = "hello"
```